# Algorithm to find boundary faces of mesh

Tags: mesh-generation, mesh

I am given the data about nodes and elements of a tetrahedral mesh. What algorithm do I use to find the boundary faces of the mesh?

Comment: Do you know the ordering of the element connectivity?

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21163/meshing-options-to-generate-number-of-the-sides-of-and-element-tetgen-triangle/21197#21197 (it is faster to sort than using a map).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, create a list of faces in the mesh. From there you should be able to create a map from faces to tets, as each face must belong to either one or two tets. The faces that belong to only one tet are your boundary faces.